# Ebean ManyToMany within Join Table?

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

I'm using ebean with play framework and I have a problem mapping a many-many relationship between 2 join tables.  Let's say we have 3 entities, Person, Company, and Profession.  A Person can have many Professions.  A Person can work for many Companies.  And a Company can employ many Persons in many Professions.

Here's my code:

```
@Entity
public class Company extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
    public List<CompanyPerson> companyPersons;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "company")
    public List<CompanyProfession> companyProfessions;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Profession extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "profession")
    public List<CompanyProfession> companyProfessions;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Person extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "person")
    public List<CompanyPerson> companyPersons;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class CompanyPerson extends Model {

    @EmbeddedId
    public CompanyPersonId id = new CompanyPersonId();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "companyPersons")
    public List<CompanyProfession> companyProfessions;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class CompanyProfession extends Model {

    @EmbeddedId
    public CompanyProfessionId id = new CompanyProfessionId();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Company company;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profession_id")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<CompanyPerson> companyPersons;
    ...
}
```

I get the following error:

> Error injecting constructor, javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error with the Join on [models.CompanyProfession.companyPersons]. Could not find the local match for [null]  Perhaps an error in a @JoinColumn
>     at play.db.ebean.EbeanDynamicEvolutions.(EbeanDynamicEvolutions.java:36)

I tried adding JoinColumn(name = "companyperson_id") but that just changed the error from [null] to [companyperson_id].
Not sure what to do here.  Any help?

Comment: Do you really need `CompanyPerson` and `CompanyProfession` models? What for? you can create simple MM relations in your base models and then get persons by profession, companies by persons etc.

Comment: There's extra data in CompanyPerson not shown here that is specific to the person's relationship with a company.  Likewise with CompanyProfession .